# Order by same name and then alphabetical

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a this value 'Мебельное производство' And I have a table which contains all the related items that has 'Мебельное производство' as a coincidence.

So far I sort it in Alphabetical way, but I need to return on the table all the coincidence with the value 'Мебельное производство' and the rest on alphabetical way.

So far I'm stucked here:

```
jQuery(".orderings tr").sort(sort).appendTo('.orderings');
function sort(a, b){
    return (jQuery(b).text()) < (jQuery(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the initial values, with the matching text, to also be sorted alphabetically (or just the ones after them)?

Comment: I added both, as you did not specify. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the first comparison, then the alpha sorting

This one does not sort the matches though:

```
jQuery(".orderings tr").sort(sort).appendTo('.orderings');
var match = "Мебельное производство";
function sort(a, b) {
    var at = jQuery(a).text();
    var bt = jQuery(b).text();
    if (at.indexOf(match) >= 0)
    {
        return -1;  // force to the top
    }
    return (bt < at) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

This one also does the initial sorting of the matches:

```
function sort(a, b) {
    var at = jQuery(a).text();
    var bt = jQuery(b).text();
    console.log(at.indexOf(match));
    if (at.indexOf(match) >= 0 && bt.indexOf(match) < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (bt.indexOf(match) >= 0 && at.indexOf(match) < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return (bt < at) ? 1 : -1;
}

var match = "Мебельное производство";
jQuery(".orderings tr").sort(sort).appendTo('.orderings');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/s7nb5o6g/5/

**Note:** the `else if` test should not be required, due to a side-effect of the sort order, but it does no harm to leave it. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/s7nb5o6g/6/ still works

Comment: Wow, it works perfect! Thank you.
One more question, can it search for example, two different matches?

Comment: @ChrisChong: Of course, but how are the two searches related? *AND* or *OR*? Do they also need to be sub-grouped? :)

Comment: For example
var match = "Мебельное производство, Строительство";
Where for example, should return all Мебельное производство, then all Строительство, and the rest alphabetically

Comment: @Chris Chong: Certainly possible, but requires a lot more work. That sounds like a perfect case for a new question. Just use the code from this answer as your starting point. :)

Comment: Any way to search var match = "Мебельное производство, Строительство" in a OR relation?

Answer (score 0):

This partial code could help you :

```
jQuery(".orderings tr").sort(sort).appendTo('.orderings');
function sort(a, b){
    // if a contains Мебельное производство, and b does not contain it, return -1
    // if b contains Мебельное производство, and a does not contain it, return 1
    // else proceed normally
    return (jQuery(b).text()) < (jQuery(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```