# Find match and sort by matches, then alphabetical

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

So far the code

```
function sort(a, b) {
var at = jQuery(a).text();
var bt = jQuery(b).text();
console.log(at.indexOf(match));
if (at.indexOf(match) >= 0 && bt.indexOf(match) < 0) {
    return -1;
}
return (bt < at) ? 1 : -1;
}

var match = "Мебельное производство";
jQuery(".orderings tr").sort(sort).appendTo('.orderings');
```

Can return all the matches over "Мебельное производство",
I want to return the match on the next way

```
var match = "Мебельное производство, Строительство";
```

And return all the matches for 'Мебельное производство' and the matches for 'Строительство', then the rest alphabetically.

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193187/order-by-same-name-and-then-alphabetical) a couple of hours ago?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's the single-match version, working above. OP is now looking to match multiple values, so it's *very* close, but I'd say not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that takes the ordering of your match strings into account.

```js
function sort(a, b) {
  var matches = match.split(/,\s*/);
  var at = jQuery(a).text();
  var bt = jQuery(b).text();

  for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i) {
    var m = matches[i];
    
    if (at.indexOf(m) >= 0 && bt.indexOf(m) < 0) {
      return -1;
    } else if (bt.indexOf(m) >= 0 && at.indexOf(m) < 0) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return (bt < at) ? 1 : -1;
}

var match = "Мебельное производство, Строительство";
jQuery(".orderings tr").sort(sort).appendTo('.orderings');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="orderings">
  <tr>
    <td>Мебельное производство</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Neither</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Строительство</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Neither</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Another Мебельное производство</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right what you want do, you can split the string and use forEach:

```
var matches = match.split(", ");

matches.forEach(function(value,index,array){
      value.sort(a,b);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, ymmv:

```
function hasText(t)
{
    return this.indexOf(t) >= 0;
}

function sort(a, b) 
{
  var at = jQuery(a).text(),
  bt = jQuery(b).text(),
  matches = match.split(/, /);
  // determine whether a or b has at least one match
  var p = matches.some(hasText, bt) - matches.some(hasText, at);

  return p ? p : at.localeCompare(bt);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/sometadino/1/)

See also: [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)